# IIS 7.0 Application On Load Event

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, iis

I've developed a WCF Rest Based Service in .NET 4.0, which is dependent on a win32 dll (on a different path). Win32 dll is static linked with a C++/CLI dll and have used spring.net for dependency injection.

Since I'm creating objects through spring, these gets created when the IIS loads the application. If the path to the win32 dll is incorrect, IIS gives out error that the C++/CLI dll or one of its dependencies could not be loaded.

```
Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Services.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
```

I tried setting the path for the IIS application using

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "path_to_win32_dll;%PATH%", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

in Global.asax: Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e), but since the application itself is not loading up, Application_Start is not getting executed.

Is there any way I can get an event in IIS Application before any of the dll's gets loaded, or a hook into the Hosting Environment so that I can set the path before the dll's get loaded.
Also is there any cache in .Net 4.0 that gets created when a dll is loaded? Is there a way to clear them off?

Comment: You must drop the native dll to %windir%\system32 or learn how to merge the native dll with your C++/CLI one.

Comment: it can't be merged with the C++/CLI as it's being used with other WIN32 application also.